# xamarin mac installation error

Tags: macos, xamarin, failed-installation

I have check several other threads, but nobody has touched on this spefic Xamarin installation error.

I'm installing Xamarin Studio on a Mac. I downloaded the dog file from Xamarin and ran it.I get the standard "Are you sure you want to open it?" message. I then click on the "Open" button. A window opens, titles, "Visual Studio for Mac - Installation" with no content and a spinning cursor. It closes and I get a "Problem Report for Install Xamarin" window with the following information:

Process:         Install_Xamarin [1672]
Path:            /Volumes/VOLUME/Install Xamarin.app/Contents/MacOS/Install_Xamarin
Identifier:      com.xamarin.universalinstaller
Version:         3.0.0 (1)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [120]

Date/Time:       2017-04-28 09:15:08.005 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.5 (11G63b)
Report Version:  9
Sleep/Wake UUID: 59EEA8E4-7B54-4380-8B95-31AEC2D5598D

Interval Since Last Report:          3584789 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           9
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  93 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   9
Anonymous UUID:                      597FF5D8-3727-4348-A273-6923618B6E3D

Crashed Thread:  0  tid_b07  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSColor colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x7fff75f69c10'

Comment: Contact Xamarin and have them help you.

Comment: I have, thank you. In the interest of getting a meaningful answer as quickly as possible, I have posted this issue in multiple developer forums, including Xamarin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone lands here instead of your Xamarin forums post:

Your OS version is too old.  From the [Xamarin System Requirements](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/requirements/) accessed May 10th, you need to have at least OS X El Capitan (10.11) or macOS Sierra. Update your operating system and try again.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain that.